# check if compilator supports boost library

Tags: c++

i am using visual c++  2010  and want to check if it supports  boost library    and if not how download it?can i do  it?

Comment: I want a compilator.  That sounds so much cooler than a compiler.

Comment: haha @Borealid. So mean but hilarious :)

Comment: Oh God. Can you imagine the questions when he starts trying to use Boost?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, I use VS2010 and Boost. (You may find bumps here or there, since VS2010 is relatively new, but generally it all works the same.)

Do keep in mind there isn't a "Boost library", per se. Boost is a collection of libraries, and you can download it and include what you want, or just strip out the libraries you want.

Comment: but how download  can you give a link?

Comment: i was  gone ok donwloaded  and install then i  can call it's library in visual c++ yes?

Comment: @davit: Once you've extracted it, setup your include directories so that Visual Studio will look at wherever you extracted it when looking to include things. Then you just `#include <boost/...>` and VS will find it.

Comment: i have extracted it on desktop then what   to ? GMan i dont know  well and please help me

Comment: @davit: Go to the project you want to use boost in, and right-click on the project name and click properties. Goto VC++ Directories and add the path to your boost under include directories.

Answer (score 0):

The Boost C++ Libraries may be found at http://www.boost.org/. The download link is http://www.boost.org/users/download/. Boost is cross-platform and should, for the most part, support Visual Studio... sometimes you will come across libraries within Boost that mention a preferred syntax vs. a more portable syntax in cases where their preferred syntax doesn't work on all compilers (typically they will list which compilers are and aren't supported for the given feature).

Answer (score 0):

[Boost for Windows](http://www.boostpro.com/download/) does not support VS 2010 in its actual
version (1.42), you have to [compile it from sources](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#invoke-bjam) or just
wait some time until it gets available.

Regards

rbo